# How to only keep posts with dates in between other dates?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some posts with some custom fields where I have a date in a string format, so I loop my posts and I convert each of them as a Date, then I do some bit to have them in order by date:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $postid = $post->ID;
    $myDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', get_post_meta($postid, 'usp-custom-80', true));
    $postOrdered[$postid] = \DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', get_post_meta($postid, 'usp-custom-80', true));
    wp_reset_query();
}
arsort($postOrdered);
var_export($postOrdered);
```

So I am attaching the date together with the ids and that gives us:

```
array ( 128288 => DateTime::__set_state(array( 'date' => '2017-08-20 20:36:02.000000', 'timezone_type' => 3, 'timezone' => 'UTC', )), 128166 => DateTime::__set_state(array( 'date' => '2017-08-17 20:36:02.000000', 'timezone_type' => 3, 'timezone' => 'UTC', )), 128308 => 
DateTime::__set_state(array( 'date' => '2017-08-05 20:36:02.000000', DateTime::__set_state(array( 'date' => '2000-03-20 20:36:02.000000', 
DateTime::__set_state(array( 'date' => '1978-05-11 20:36:02.000000', 'timezone_type' => 3, 'timezone' => 'UTC', )), 128295 => 
DateTime::__set_state(array( 'date' => '1978-04-10 20:36:02.000000', 'timezone_type' => 3, 'timezone' => 'UTC', )), 128337 =>
 DateTime::__set_state(array( 'date' => '1978-03-16 20:36:02.000000', 'timezone_type' => 3, 'timezone' => 'UTC', )), 128315 => DateTime::__set_state(array( 'date' => '1976-08-10 20:36:02.000000', 'timezone_type' => 3, 'timezone' => 'UTC', )), 128290 => DateTime::__set_state(array( 'date' => '1970-04-12 20:36:02.000000', 'timezone_type' => 3, 'timezone' => 'UTC', )), )
```

OK now what we do is **GET** some $start and $end dates from a `form` using `GET`

```
$start = $_GET['start']; 
$end = $_GET['end'];
$start  = \DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', $start);
$end  = \DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', $end);
var_dump($start);
var_dump($end);
```

And that gives us:

```
object(DateTime)#8267 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-02-01 20:51:56.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" } 
object(DateTime)#7974 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-02-05 20:51:56.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }
```

Now what i am trying to do is a simple check if any of those posts have any date in between our $start and $end and display them order ASC or DESC

Literally something like

```
if ( ( $myDate >= $start) && ( $myDate <= $end) ) {
 ...my posts...
```

But that still gives us all posts regardless

Comment: Assuming you have `$start` and `$end` defined before your posts loop, you should be able to just test `$myDate` before pushing into `$postOrdered` e.g. `if ( ( $myDate >= $start) && ( $myDate <= $end) ) $postOrdered[$postid] = $myDate;`

Comment: thing is it is not getting in, i don't understand it check this for example https://pastebin.com/rK0EnNeX

Comment: for dates, use the ANSI format YYYY-MM-DD and check that you are comparing dates and dates and not dates and times

Comment: You can compare `DateTime` objects directly, you don't need to convert them to timestamps first. But if you do, note that `format` returns a string, so you should use e.g. `$end = (int)$end->format('U');` to be able to compare them properly

Comment: @DavidBray I still no posts  `$start = $_GET['start']; 
 $end = $_GET['end'];
 $start  = \DateTime::createFromFormat('YYYY-MM-DD', $start);
 $end  = \DateTime::createFromFormat('YYYY-MM-DD', $end);` and then `foreach($posts as $post) {
         $postid = $post->ID;
         $myDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('YYYY-MM-DD', get_post_meta($postid, 'usp-custom-80', true));
         if ( ( $myDate >= $start) && ( $myDate <= $end) ) {
             $postOrdered[$postid] = $myDate;`

Comment: @Nick nothing, still not working https://pastebin.com/QF9FJkyP

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to demonstrate in your pastebin? you have 3 numbers, but you are not doing anything with them.

Comment: @nick what i am realising is that each time I refresh, those numbers increase, and looks like as time passed e.g. seconds. And also that my date = 953510795 has a strange number, because is totally different from start and end, like it has a completely different date, finally if I do if ( ( $myDate >= $start) && ( $myDate <= $end) ) it's like not comparing at all

Comment: Some of the dates in your data are very close to the Unix Epoch (Jan 1 1970) so the values are much lower than start and end. that's what you are seeing with 953510795. Based on the data you have posted, I would not expect to see any posts in your output as the most recent date is 2017 and your start and end values are both in 2019.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187959/discussion-between-rob-m-and-nick).

Comment: @Nick you mean some of the posts might be broken with its date? I thought the loop would continue to the next post if something was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just compare `DateTime` objects directly, so your code can be written as:

```
$start = \DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', $_GET['start']);
$end = \DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', $_GET['end']);
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $postid = $post->ID;
    $myDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', get_post_meta($postid, 'usp-custom-80', true));
    if (($myDate >= $start) && ($myDate <= $end)) {
        $postOrdered[$postid] = (int)$myDate->format('U');
    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Note that all the dates on your posts are before 2019, so you will need to adjust your `$start` value to see any posts in the output.

To get a sorted list of unique dates, use this code after the `foreach` loop:

```
$postOrdered = array_unique($postOrdered);
arsort($postOrdered);
```