# How to convert date to strtotime?

Tags: php

I have the following

```
$start = $_GET['start']; 
$start  = \DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', $start);
$start = strtotime($start);
var_dump($start);
```

The result is

```
bool(false)
```

If I do

```
$start  = \DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', $start);
var_dump($start);
```

I get

```
object(DateTime)#8267 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-02-01 23:26:08.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" } bool(false)
```

Comment: Doesn't `strtotime` take a string? You're passing in an object. Perhaps `strtotime($start->date)` ?

Comment: if i check what of I am getting it says it is a string tho

Comment: @jhnc i am really trying to resolve this and I am hours on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542905/how-to-only-keep-posts-with-dates-in-between-other-dates

Comment: ? The last line of your question says it's an object. Does it have a `__toString` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a unix timestamp, use [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) with [`'U'`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) specifier:

```
$start = $_GET['start']; 
$start  = \DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', $start);
echo $start->format('U');
```

Comment: I need to convert them in order to be able to check if a  date is between other dates, it's driving me crazy, I don't understand what I am doing wrong, I have this open and i trying anything possible https://stackoverflow.com/q/54542905/1018804